# Speech recognition in python to include the whole duration

Tags: python, speech-recognition

In the following code, I have an issue with speech recognition. The audio WAV file duration is 4 seconds only, however I can only got the transcript for only the last two seconds.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

audio_data = sr.AudioFile('f1.wav')
recognizer = sr.Recognizer()

with audio_data as file_audio:
    print("Start Transcribing File ...")
    recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(file_audio)
    file_audio = recognizer.record(file_audio)
    print(recognizer.recognize_google(file_audio))
```

Any idea how to fix that or how to convert the audio file to WAV to specific setttings that allows me to get the whole transcript?

Comment: What are the number of channels, the sample rate, and bit depth of the audio clip? Have you viewed its waveform or spectrograph to make sure there's nothing like a DC offset, ground loop or any other potential issues?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have no idea about such stuff. Can you guide me to a tutorial for such a stuff?

Comment: Those are all very basic audio things, Google should be able to get you what you need.